# Print a single row from db's table with "fetch_array" in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, mysqli

That's my first post so sorry if my question has already been answered but I hadn't found any question similar to mine.
I'll explain my problem: I've created a table on my db's account and I'm trying to print on a page a row of that table (the row is choosed by the user) but I can't find out a solution.

I must use "mysqli_fetch_array" but, despite I've searched everywhere, I can't solve that problem.
My idea was that rows increment with the User ID (because of the "AUTO_INCREMENT" in the db's table) so I'd like to know if there's a way to match the row choosed by the user and the ID in my table.

That's what I've done until now (of course in php):

```
$conn=mysqli_connect($hostaddr,$username,$password,$db);
if($conn==NULL){
    echo "Error!";
}else{
    $result=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM Anagrafica");
    if($result==NULL){
        echo "Error!";
    }else{
        $arr=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        if($arr==NULL){
            echo "Error!";
        }else{
            $r=$_POST['Row'];
            $rows=mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if($r>$rows){
                echo "<p><b>The row doesn't exists!</b></p>";
            }else{                                           //here is where I can't find a solution
                $ID=$arr['UserID'];
                $Name=$arr['Name'];
                $Email=$arr['Email'];
                echo "UserID $ID - $Name <br> Email: $Email";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `WHERE UserId = id` substituting the correct id for `id`.

Comment: Try to use WHERE clause

Comment: So like $q=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM Anagrafica WHERE UserID=id"); and I put id=$r?

Comment: Almost. It should be  `"SELECT * FROM Anagrafica WHERE UserID=?"` and then mysql will substitute ? with the actual id. See the linked answer for the proper example